# Selecting "uniqueidentifier" type in cfquery

Tags: sql-server, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I need to select a row where identifier matches my variable. Let's say, my variable value is "myvariable" (in uniqueidentifier form, of course).

```
<cfset current_user_id = "myvariable">
```

Here's my "cfquery" content:

```
<cfquery name="findUser" datasource="#SOURCE#">
    SELECT
        db.[User].UserID
    FROM
        db.[User]
    WHERE
        db.[User].UserID = "#current_user_id#";
</cfquery>
```

It returns the following error:

> [Macromedia][SQLServer JDBC Driver][SQLServer]Invalid column name
>   'myvariable'.

The data and query is fine. A cfdump of `SELECT *` returns all of the rows, but the addition of the `WHERE` clause causes an error. The query works fine, outside ColdFusion, even with `WHERE` clause.

I tried adding this, but it doesn't work either:

```
<cfqueryparam value = "#current_user_id#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_idstamp">
```

Is there something I should know about selecting the "uniqueidentifier" type with conditions? Maybe I need to set the type of my variable to "uniqueidentifier" somehow?

CF version 10,0

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The first one fails as you want to use single quotes not double quotes for values. So `'#current_user_id#'`. The cfqueryparam looks OK - do you get the same error with that or a different error? Also which CF version are you using - you've tagged 9, 10 & 11

Comment: I changed double quotes to single quotes and it worked. Thank you!

Comment: For the query parameter, try changing the datatype to varchar.

Answer (score 0):

eg:

```
<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="1890958b-dec9-0dfc-c372-306a897693ea" />
```

Note this is using a MSSQL compatible version of a UUID from the CFLIB.ORG CreateGUID() function.

Answer (score 0):

> Tried adding [cfqueryparam] but it doesn't work either:

Does not work *how*? Essentially, a [uniqueidentifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187942.aspx) will be handled as a [fixed length string](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378878(v=sql.110).aspx). As long as you supply the correct value, any of the base types used for characters is fine:

- `CF_SQL_CHAR`
- `CF_SQL_VARCHAR`
- `CF_SQL_IDSTAMP` (just a synonym for `CF_SQL_CHAR`)

All of those types work fine with ColdFusion 10/11 and SQL Server 2008. So the problem is likely due to a difference in your data or code.

**DDL:**

```
CREATE TABLE TestTable ( UserID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, UserName VARCHAR(100) );
```

**CODE:**

```
<cfset current_user_id = "6F9619FF-8B86-D011-B42D-00C04FC964FF">

<!--- 1:   CF_SQL_IDSTAMP --->
<cfquery name="qTest">
    SELECT  UserID
    FROM    TestTable 
    WHERE   UserID = <cfqueryparam value = "#current_user_id#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_idstamp"> 
</cfquery>

<!--- 2:   CF_SQL_CHAR --->
<cfquery name="qTest">
    SELECT  UserID, UserName
    FROM    TestTable 
    WHERE   UserID = <cfqueryparam value = "#current_user_id#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_char"> 
</cfquery>

<!--- 3:   CF_SQL_VARCHAR --->
<cfquery name="qTest">
    SELECT  UserID, UserName
    FROM    TestTable 
    WHERE   UserID = <cfqueryparam value = "#current_user_id#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar"> 
</cfquery>
```

> changed double quotes to single quotes and it worked

Though technically you can use quotes - don't. `CFQueryparam` provides a lot more benefits. For example, you no longer have to worry about quoting strings ;-) Not to mention things like - sql injection protection, data type checking, improved query performance, etcetera.