# An exception occurred while trying to read the image

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, coldfusion-10, coldfusion-8, coldfusion-11

This works fine:

```
<cfset image="http://netdna.webdesignerdepot.com/uploads/2008/11/sample-graphic.jpg">
<cfimage action="INFO" source="#image#" structname="objImageInfo" name="myImage">
```

This gives an error:

```
<cfset image="http://www.freedigitalphotos.net/images/img/homepage/87357.jpg">
<cfimage action="INFO" source="#image#" structname="objImageInfo" name="myImage">
```

*An exception occurred while trying to read the image.
coldfusion.image.ImageReader$ImageReadingException: An exception occurred while trying to read the image.*

**Why?**

Comment: Image functionality and bug fixes varied a LOT between versions 8 and 11.  Exactly *which version* are you using that throws that error?

Comment: I think the issue here is that freedigitalphotos.net has some form of hotlink protection. They probably block requests from invalid user agents or requests. If you look at the error it will probably tell you its returning a 403 Forbidden on that image.

Comment: Good catch. If you read the *full* error message, that is the problem. @EduardClimov - I did not down vote it, but as mentioned on [your last question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38970803/selecting-uniqueidentifier-type-in-cfquery), please help us to help you ;-) Many things will vary by version, so please use the tags to indicate the specific version you are using.

Comment: Thank you for the help! 
I will indicate my version next time, @Leigh :)

Comment: Thanks. So what version *are* you using? :)  That information would definitely assist in answering your other question. If you are not sure, use `<cfdump var="#server#">`.

Comment: productversion 10,0

Comment: I'm curious on this. When i am checking that both URL using IsImageFile() on CF10. When checking this isImageFile("http://netdna.webdesignerdepot.com/uploads/2008/11/sample-graphic.jpg") the result gives "Yes" and isImageFile("http://www.freedigitalphotos.net/images/img/homepage/87357.jpg") it gives "No". I think it may be the site have some access limitation.

Comment: It is as [haxtb already explained above](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38976433/an-exception-occurred-while-trying-to-read-the-image#comment65312380_38976433). The target site probably blocks "automated requests" - deliberately. You should read their Terms and Conditions to see whether or not it is actually allowed according to their site rules.  Most likely it is not, which would explain you are getting a 403 error.

Answer (score 1):

We can able to read the image as binary data using "ReadBinary" action then getting the image info using "INFO" action. The code should like as following..

```
<cfif not isImageFile("http://www.freedigitalphotos.net/images/img/homepage/87357.jpg")>

   <cffile action="readbinary" file="http://www.freedigitalphotos.net/images/img/homepage/87357.jpg" variable="strFile">
   <cfset oImage = imageNew(strFile)>   
   <cfimage action="INFO" source="#oImage#" structname="objImageInfo" name="myImage">  

   <cfdump var="#objImageInfo#" /> 
</cfif>
```

I found this solution at here.. http://www.oscararevalo.com/blog/index.cfm/2008/1/26/cfimage-and-pjpeg-images